# My favicon for my HTML website does not show

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages, favicon

I'm building a website in HTML, and hosting it via GitHub Pages. You can take a look of it here: http://marcuscodes.me/

It has previously shown normally with this code:

I also tried using favicons:

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico?">
```

I have tried adding a ? to my path as shown here:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico?">
```

However, it still does not show.
I have tried these steps:

- Refreshing browser cache
- Using different browser
- using different device

You can view the full source code here. https://github.com/inkthought-labs/website

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't see `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico?">` or anything of the sort in your index.html.

Comment: Remove questions mark from href attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **index.html**, you used this to supposedly create the favicon:

```
<link rel="icon" href="https://i.ibb.co/SBX2vY1/inkthoughtinvis.png">
```

However, you forgot the type attribute. It should be:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://i.ibb.co/SBX2vY1/inkthoughtinvis.png" />
```

Additional note: If permitted by copyright licenses, it is best that you download the image to your local storage and then set the location into the **href** attribute. In the scenario that the website host removes the image, it will not display.

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://i.ibb.co/SBX2vY1/inkthoughtinvis.png" />
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! It isn't working, maybe it's the host issues?

Comment: Works like a charm for me. Did you remember to replace the older one?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response, I’ll try that tomorrow.

Comment: Alright. As always, if this solved your problem, please consider accepting. Also, I've [tested the image](https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker?protocol=https&site=i.ibb.co%2FSBX2vY1%2Finkthoughtinvis.png#.X2YiOxBKiUk) for good measure, and it seems to be working fine (for desktop, at least).

Comment: Congrats! @geneva